# Pigpio - Servo: Do you need to wait for a certain amount of time after set_servo_pulsewidth()

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo, pigpio

I'm using the pigpio module to program some Servo motors. After using the `set_servo_pulsewidth()` function do I need to use `time.sleep()`? Or is it safe for the Servo motor to carry on to the next `set_servo_pulsewidth()` function without the wait?
(P.S. I'm using pigpio to reduce the jitter in the Servo motors and I haven't found any other solution to the jitter)

Comment: It might depend on your specific servo what the maximum repetition rate is, but there’s clearly no point trying to update the pulsewidth faster than the repetition rate that pigpio uses.

Comment: Changing the servo pulsewidth too often might be contributing to your servo jittering. You might try slowing changes down a lot more, or filterng them to change more slowly. If servo repetition rate is nominally 20ms, changing the servo pulse width more often than e.g 0.1-0.2-0.5s could cause the servo to continually jitter.